# Jquery and Intellisense in VS 2008 with hotfix and SP1

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I followed Scott Guthrie's instructions 
as outlined at
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

but no avail: intellisense still doesn't work.

Any tips?

Comment: Has nothing to do with ASP.Net

Comment: @Ikke Yes it does.  You would not be using jQuery in VS2008 unless you were building a web app with ASP.NET

Comment: We also use VS2008 for classic ASP. Even I have used it for just browsing through and looking into PHP projects when I was trying to understand how CakePHP works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the bug:
my script tag said

```
<script type="text/javascript" source="Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```